# Getting a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino Uno to Work Together

Tags: arduino

I am trying to figure out different ways to get my Arduino Uno R3 and Raspberry Pi 2 B to work together. I am looking for suggestions/projects that I can do that include both the Arduino and Pi working together. Are there any projects out there that let you do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most reliable projects I found:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi07.pdf

It uses Python and the Firmata protocol. You're going to need to install arduino software on the RasPi (`sudo apt-get install arduino`).

Basically what happens here is that the Firmata on the Arduino interacts with Python to control the Arduino. It's limited as PyFirmata takes over the whole board, but unless you're doing something really complicated you're good.